# Calf Slicer vs Vaporizer

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, grappling, jujutsu

I'm just curious to know the exact difference/s between the Jiu Jitsu moves '[Calf Slicer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZLh7ETdDAU)' and '[Vaporizer](http://thedragonzone.com/2013/mma-video-training-tips/jiu-jitsu-training-tips/vaporizer-leg-lock-eddie-bravo/)'. Do both submissions affect to the calf or they work differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A calf slicer is a compression lock that crushes the calf muscle, and I've heard the terms "calf crush", "calf slicer", and "calf crank" all used interchangeably. At [2:00 of this video](http://youtu.be/G1tIzC2FIfg?t=1m59s), Eddie Bravo describes the Vaporizer as a "toe hold slash **calf crank**, slash devastation...this one is very hard to resist." (Emphasis mine.)

So there's an element of calf slicer in the Vaporizer, but it's also got elements of a toe hold, which is a separate knee-torquing attack. There is overlap between a plain calf slicer and the Vaporizer but they're not the same.

Comment: Well, I saw few variations in 'vaporizer' submission, and toe hold is one of them. Yet, I suppose both submissions target the calf as the main submitting area. Anyway, thanks a lot for providing your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

In a calf crank the movement is in line with the foot-ankle-shin structure, while in the vaporizer it's not: this creates **torque** on the hip/knee/ankle joints, which is a movement pattern not found in a calf crank.

This twisting motion is found instead in many other submissions such as the toe hold, heel hook, kimura and omoplata. You might think of the vaporizer as an **omoplata** on his leg combined with a **calf crank**.

In other words, if in the calf slicer you are using his lower leg as a **prybar** and your shin as a **wedge**, in the vaporizer you are *also* using his leg like a **wrench**.